# Component communication in angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, custom-component

Angular 1.5 component communication suggestions usually have output bindings to invoke methods on root controllers.

Let's say I have a root component, and two child components.

```
<root>
    <child-1></child-1>
    <child-2></child-2>
</root>
```

It'd like to react to a button click on component one by reading a value on component two and then doing something in the root.

For example, `child-1` is a directive which wraps a drawing library that attaches a drawing to its DOM node and has a variable to control that drawing.

`child-2` has a button. When it is clicked, data from the `child-1` variable should be passed on to root which does something with it.

Specifically, `child-1` wraps `var graph2d = new vis.Graph2d(container, dataset, options);`. Later on, I would like to retrieve some information from `graph2d` and pass it on to `root` to do something with it.

This boils down to: how can components react to events issued by other components? The inputs and outputs suggestions don't seem to cover that scenario.

Comment: Use two way binding and inject the data in both components: `child-1 <-> Controller <-> child-2`

Comment: @zeroflagL basically, I'm asking how can two disjoint components communicate with inputs and outputs in situations where one would need to react on event from another.

Comment: You can hold the state on a higher level component, or you can communicate between components by using $rootScope.$broadcast

Comment: From what I understand the root component holds the relevant data (or at least has access to it) , the child-2 component fires an event to which the root component reacts.

Answer (score 4):

In angular 1.5 you can use **require** and/or **property bindings** (input/output) to communicate.

If you use the require property then your root component would publish an api and your child component would get a reference to the controller:

```
angular.module('app').component('child1', {
   bindings: {},
   require: {api: '^root'}, //your <root> component
   template: '',
   controller: controller
});
```

You can then use the **methods** of the root component in your child component:

```
$ctrl.api.addWatchedBook();
```

This is the root component controller function:

```
$ctrl.addWatchedBook = addWatchedBook;

function addWatchedBook(bookName){

  booksWatched.push(bookName);

}
```

Here is a complete **architectual overview**: [Component Communications](https://github.com/kevinvanhove/angular-structure-styleguide/blob/master/README.md#component_communications)

Comment: Is using `require` considered the best approach when a child component needs to respond to async requests? i.e. an edit form component that delegates its save method to a parent via an `&` binding, but needs to react to server error/success callbacks from the parent?

Comment: I dont feel this is a good approach since a child knows the parent component. It should be the inverse. A child should only emit events/functions through its bindings with `&` where a parent/container component will bind to it.