# Angular 1.5. Components communication. Best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, communication

I'm using Angular 1.5.9.

Right now I have two components which need to communicate.
If I change something in the first one (for example choose item in the list) => second one needs to be changed (item that was chosen needs to be displayed) and vice versa (changing in the second one => change in the first one)
I have read about a lot of approaches, so I can manage this in few ways:

1. Communication via shareable Service
2. Using two way data binding ("=" option in component bindings). Example: `https://jsfiddle.net/peter_drinnan/t4q4nrfp/27/`
3. Using one way data binding with input/output approach. Example: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033940/how-to-pass-data-between-child-components-in-angular-1-5-not-using-scope`
4. Using "require" (some parent component to share data). Example: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645065/component-communication-in-angular-1-5`

Maybe I miss something?
What is the best practice?

Thank you.